# kdevelop: editing CMakeLists.txt

Tags: c++, cmake

I am having troubles trying to make my project work with kdevelop.

In the CMakeLists.txt I have included the paths to the libraries that I use:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.4.6)
PROJECT(Ormapi)
INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES("/dir/whatever/local/dir/include") < here is defined global.h
INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES("/dir/whatever/local/src")    

ADD_EXECUTABLE(Ormapi main.cpp OrmAPI.cpp)
```

main.cpp uses an instance of the class I have defined in OrmAPI.cpp. 
The problem is when I try to create an instance of any other class defined in the above included_directories, I get the both errors "undefined reference to " and  "undefined reference to ".

This is the call from the constructor of OrmAPI.cpp (Global is the class that exists inside the included directories):

```
OrmAPI::OrmAPI(){        
 Global::dirs()->addResourceDir("mydir");    

}
```

I am 99% sure that it is related with the CMakeLists.txt, but I do not know what on Earth can be happening.

Any directions?

Comment: Try to make it more clear how your paths are being included.  Instead of using '...' use a fake dir like `INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES("/fake/dir/src")`

Answer (score 4):

Finally found the problem:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.4.6)
PROJECT(Ormapi)
INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES("/dir/whatever/local/dir/include") < here is defined global.h
INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES("/dir/whatever/local/src")    

ADD_EXECUTABLE(Ormapi main.cpp OrmAPI.cpp)
target_link_libraries(Ormapi /dirdir/lib.so) <<<
```

Since I am creating instances of objects declared in those paths, I have to include a shared library too. But It has to be after the ADD_EXECUTABLE.  I was reading the tree of dependencies from the other side.

BTW: I found [here](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/documentation.html) a huge ammount of interesting information about dealing with Makefiles, CMakeLists, etc..